# Outllok add in REST call: RequestBroker-ParseUri -- "Resource not found for the segment 'Q7GceiTKAvvXBwAtYompjmwrRqF359uQTkd1AAAAQTkd1AAAHjsV0AAA='."

Tags: outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, outlook-restapi, ms-office-addin

I am using Outlook add in REST call to get attachment details. But I am receiving an error that says:

{
"error": {
"code": "RequestBroker--ParseUri",
"message": "Resource not found for the segment 'Q7GceiTKAvvXBwAtYompjmwrRqF359uQTkd1AAAAAAEJAAAtYompjmwrRqF359uQTkd1AAAHjsV0AAA='."
}
}

This is my code:

```
const encodedItemId = encodeURIComponent(Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId);
Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({ isRest: true }, async function (result) {
if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {

    const callbackToken = result.value;
    // Construct the URL to download attachment content
    const attachmentUrl = 'https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/' + encodedItemId+ "/attachments";
    const headers = { Authorization: `Bearer ${callbackToken}` };
    // Fetch attachment content
    fetch(attachmentUrl, { headers })
        .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
        .then(arrayBuffer => {
        const attachmentName = attachment.name;
        const base64Data = arrayBufferToBase64(arrayBuffer);
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log("Failed to fetch attachment content:", error);
});
```

I have also tried other variations to construct url, like

const attachmentUrl = `${Office.context.mailbox.restUrl}/v2.0/me/messages/${item.itemId}/attachments/${attachmentId}/$value`;

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should use RestID instead of EWSID which is Based64 but not URL safe.